# Locating a installation

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, locate

Hello I would like to find a file called `lyxpipe` (which is used by the program lyx). However, I don't have a idea where the program is installed.

I typed

```
locate lyx
lyx: /usr/bin/lyx2.0 /usr/bin/X11/lyx2.0 /usr/share/lyx2.0
```

However, when I try to navigate to the folders I can type

```
pwd
home/Theodor
```

where Theodor is my username.

But there is no other folder `bin` in this directory. Can somebody tell me how to access these paths?

Comment: try: ls -a ~
on your terminal.
Is there a .bin ?

Comment: 13.04 is off topic on askubuntu since it is end of life. Please upgrade to 13.10 or 14.04 LTS to keep up with security issues and keep your system safer.

Answer (score 3):

The location of the pipe is set in "Edit→Preferences→Inputs→Paths". Most likely the default is:

```
~/.lyx/lyxpipe
```

(so that is your home dir and then hidden directory .lyx; if you do `ls -a|more` in you home dir it will show all hidden files including .lyx).

LyX adds the '.in' and '.out' suffixes while creating the pipes so the names are going to be `lyxpipe.in`  and `lyxpipe.out`.

---

Regarding lyx itself.

```
 which lyx
```

will show you the place of the executable and it will show:

```
/usr/bin/lyx2.0
```

That is not a directory in your home but in the /usr/ directory. This directory is in your PATH so you can execute it from anywhere on your system by typing "lyx2.0".

Comment: hey...i try to link jabref and lyx and I entered the lyx server path to home/Theodor/.lyx/lyxpipe (which is the path that is in jabref as well) but still if i try to push the refs it doesnt work

Comment: That should be correct...

Comment: yes i know but i really dont have a idea which thing prevents it from working...if i check the directory i dont file find a file lyxpipe ....

Comment: check permissions of the files. Only thing I can imagine being wrong.

Comment: how would you ange the permission?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0):

To change directory to /usr/bin/

`cd /usr/bin`

To execute binary file /usr/bin/lyx2.0

`/usr/bin/lyx2.0`

Comment: if i tyope cd /usr/bin this works but if i type cd /usr/bin/.lyx it says there is no file or directory

Comment: why dont you do `locate .lyx` after doing a `sudo updatedb`